# Source code of android messaging

Tags: android-source, android-sms

I am planning to create an application which the user can put security to their SMS. Is there a possibility for me to see the source code of the Messaging of Android phone? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [this](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/2.0_r1/com/android/mms/ui/ComposeMessageActivity.java) class on Grep Code. You can look around and see if it works for you. However, for anything related to SMS, you probably do not need to change the source code, just intercept calls at appropriate places !

Comment: thanks for the link.. where can i view the source code of its manifest and xml of it?

Comment: On the left hand side Navigation Bar, click on the Files tab and you'll be able to see the whole source.

Answer (score 12):

Android source code is also mirrored on Github. The SMS/MMS package can be found on: https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_mms

Answer (score 10):

See https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Mms for the Android Messaging app.